# Installed Mysgit for windows and Git bash is returning dev/null

Tags: windows, git

I did an standard installation of git for windows. However when I opened git gui these what I've seen in my screen[image]

and as for git bash.

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.4-preview20140815)


    Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
    Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory

    John@KYEL-PC ~
    $ cd projects/
    sh.exe": /dev/null: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and this is still what I get

Comment: What options are you using when you install MySysGit?

Comment: default installation. it works on my other unit except for ths one

Answer (score 0):

Obviosly you are using a very old Git Version. That was a [bug fixed nearly 20.February 2014](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/6):

> On line 75:
>
> ```
> newFilePath = '/dev/null'; // do something for Windows!
> ```
>
> You can use 'NUL' path for Windows like:
>
> ```
> newFilePath = 'NUL';
> ```

Remove this old version and try to install [this one](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140815/Git-1.9.4-preview20140815.exe)!

Comment: I already did that. I already installed the latest one but the error still persist